# Laravel 5.4 - choose route based on role

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have following code:

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {

        dd($user);
        Route::get('/', 'SiteController@index');
    });
```

The **$user** is created in the **AppServiceProvider**, but it is not accessible in the **Route**:

```
public function boot()
    {
        view()->composer('layouts.main', function($view){

            $employees     = \App\Bamboo::getEmployees();
            $employeeIndex = \App\Bamboo::getEmployeeIndex(auth()->user()->email, $employees);

            $view->with('employees', $employees);
            $view->with('user', $employees['employees'][$employeeIndex]);
        });
    }
```

Is there a why for me to choose which function will be called in the **SiteController** based on the **role** (this is contained in the $user)?

I want to do something like this:

```
$method = $user->role === 'dev' ? 'index' : 'admin';

Route::get('/', "SiteController@{$method}");
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Define a middleware for the routes with roles: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware

Comment: I am kinda lost here  - I don't see a way how I can pass **user** to the middleware (the one created in the AppServiceProvider

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
if($user->role === 'dev)
   Route::get('/', "SiteController@index");
else
   Route::get('/', "SiteController@admin");
```

Another easy way would be if you define a function in the Site controller which checks what the $user is and then returns another route like this :

```
public function getRoute(Request $r){
  if(Auth::user()->role === 'dev')
    return $this->index($r);
  else
    return $this->admin($r);
}
```